# Should we say "in the home page" or "on the home page"?

Tags: prepositions

I've to write the following sentence:
In the home page, select xxxx from the xxxx panel.

Should I use "in the home page" or "on the home page"?

Comment: I would say "on the home page" is better.

Answer (score 2):

The usual phrase is 'on the home page'. This is because 'home page' follows the same rule as a page in a book. With books, we also say 'on the page', not 'in the page'. See the [comparative usage of both phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20home%20page%2Con%20the%20home%20page&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20home%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20home%20page%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20home%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20home%20page%3B%2Cc0)

However, in the context of your sentence, it *may possibly* be acceptable to say 'in the home page', because you are asking people to *find* XXXX 'in the home page'. It's equivalent to saying 'find XXXX *in* the panels *on* the home page'. However I would still say it is safer to say 'on'.

It is interesting to note that, while we say 'in the book', we tend usually to say 'on the website' and always 'on the internet'. I presume this is because a website has a sense of a 'broadcast' media. In English, we are used to things being 'on the radio' or 'on the television', so 'on the internet' also makes sense.

But there are some phrases where the concept may be new enough that a hard and fast rule for a preposition has not been settled upon. For instance, I would consider both 'on my blog' or 'in my blog' as valid, although the former is more common. Compare: [in my blog](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20my%20blog%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) and [on my blog](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20my%20blog%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)